# Retrieve JSON value with random generated value

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I've got a JSON file that looks like this. It's basically a JSON file taken stright from Wikipedia using their API.

```
{
    "batchcomplete": "",
    "query": {
        "pages": {
          "31329803": {
            "pageid": 31329803,
            "ns": 0,
            "title": "Wiki Title",
            "extract": "<p><b>Your Wiki Title</b></p>"
          }
        }
    }
}
```

The number generated under **"pages"** (which is the pageID) is random. I'm trying to retrieve the **"extract"** value, but I can't seem to get it.

I'm using Visual Studio & using NewtonSoft JSON.net for parsing. I've created a class for retrieving the data I want, and it looks like this.

```
    public class WikiPage
    {
        public string title { get; set; }
        public int pageid { get; set; }
        public int ns { get; set; }
        public string extract { get; set; }
    }
```

I'm trying to bypass the JSON tree & get the value I want. The code I use to get the value are as follows:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
   // Getting JSON string from file            
   string JSONString = File.ReadAllText("wiki.json");

   JObject wikiSearchResult = JObject.Parse(JSONString);
   IList<JToken> wikiPages = wikiSearchResult["query"]["pages"].Children().ToList();

   JToken result = wikiPages[0];
   var wp = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<WikiPage>(result.ToString());

   // Writing data
   Console.WriteLine(wp.extract);
   Console.ReadLine();
}
```

When I run the program program, I get an error:

> An unhandled exception of type
>   'Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException' occurred in
>   Newtonsoft.Json.dll
>
> Additional information: Error converting value "31329803" to type
>   'JSON_test.WikiPage'. Path '', line 1, position 10.

I've tried many things, but no luck. Maybe there is a simpler way to do it, but I'm pretty much stuck right now, can someone help me?

Comment: Wow, a question that contains all the relevant information to solve it. A unicorn!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're almost done, just get `result` this way:

```
JToken result = wikiPages[0].Children().First();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't deserialize a key value pair like that. Try this instead :

```
var json = JObject.Parse(JSONString);
var pages = json["query"]["pages"].ToObject<Dictionary<string, WikiPage>>();

var page = pages.First().Value;
Console.WriteLine(page.extract);
```